# How to recover data from a screen-bricked phone?

Tags: backup, security, unbricking

#### Situation

I've got a Samsung Galaxy Fame with a broken touch screen. The owner had it protected with a pattern, and as I am unable to make this pattern with a broken screen, I cannot mount the storage in order to backup/recover data.

Some information:

- Power, volume and home button are still working
- I can get into recovery and download mode
- The phone is stock (No custom/unlocked bootloder and no CWM)
- USB-debugging is (unfortunately) disabled

What I've tried:

- Connecting a mouse using OTG
- Connecting to the phone using ADB
  This did not work because I could not mount the sd card because I had no sudo permissions.
- Using a magnet on the screen

I would like to refer to the following question that concerns the same problem but did not give me a solution:
[Android ADB Shell Recovery Mounting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39623/android-adb-shell-recovery-mounting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2786395. Its a program that can mirror your phone to computer. There is also information to enable USB Debugging if you had that disabled.

Hope my answer helps!

Comment: This requires usb debugging to be enabled

Comment: This requires usb debugging to be enabled. The trick mentioned to enable that requires me to be root.

Comment: @Peter and why don't you root your device... Install CWM from fastboot...

Comment: @SuperThosmasLab Is that possible without usb debugging turned on?

Comment: No, not always. And have you already tried the trick? I don't think you'll need root because its from the recovery mode... @Peter